# How to select the 1st third, 2nd third and 3rd third of a data set?

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that returns a list of locations by zone that gets run as a clause in a query. The problem is, I need to break up the list of locations into three separate parts so that I can run the master query on each of the three groups. For example, Zone 1 returns a count of 15 locations. I want to get the first 5, run my report, then get the second 5, run my report, and finally the last 5 and run my report. This needs to be dynamic as new locations will be added or removed.

```
select Distinct Zone, location from dbo.globalLocations where zone = 'ZoneSE'
zone     Location
ZoneSE   FL1
ZoneSE   FL2
ZoneSE   FL3
ZoneSE   GA1
ZoneSE   GA2
ZoneSE   AL1
ZoneSE   AL2
ZoneSE   SC1
ZoneSE   SC2
```

I need to return the first 5 locations, then the second (4 in this case).

Comment: Please provide your table schema, sample data, sample output, and what you have tried already.

Comment: how did you get that formated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you consider NTILE() function?

Comment: Thank you i used a NTILE. select * from(
SELECT zone, ''''+Location +'''' as Location,
NTILE(3) OVER (order by Location DESC)AS GrpNum from
(select distinct Zone, Location from dbo.globalLocations  where Zone = substring(@zone, 1, (len(@Zone) - 1)) group by Zone, Location )x)y

Answer (score 0):

Lee,
You can accomplish what you're after using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`. For example:

```
DECLARE @Divisor int = 3
DECLARE @PartNo int = 3
DECLARE @Total int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IR_Doc_Ref)
DECLARE @SegLength int = @Total/@Divisor
DECLARE @Skip int = (@PartNo - 1) * @SegLength
DECLARE @Take int = @SegLength

SELECT * FROM Zones
ORDER BY ID --Any row will do here.
OFFSET (@Skip) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@Take) ROWS ONLY
```

This assumes, of course, that your record count is evenly dividable by the divisor. If not, you'll need to incorporate the modulus(%) operator. Hope this helps.